# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: AIRMap was not found in the UIManager react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm working with React Native and I need a Map on my Application, for this, I'm trying to use react-native-maps. But when I get it installed, and try to use it, I got these red screens:

[image]

I've followed all the steps to installation and examples in this link:

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps

Nothing is wrong in my view code, but perhaps something is missing in configuration.

This is my Environment:

```
"react-native-maps": "github:react-community/react-native-maps"
"react": "16.5.0"
"react-native": "0.57.0"
```

I'm using the github link to add react-native-maps because some people said this in the Issues page of the react-native-maps (here is a link that one collaborator is saying that > https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/2539#issuecomment-428291213 < ), but even doing this it doesn't work.

I forgot to mention that when linked the lib, this happens:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, D:\Projetos\atitur\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes. Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s 48 actionable tasks: 24 executed, 24 up-to-date Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Comment: did you follow this: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md based on the error it seems you did not link the library

Comment: you need to link the lib

Comment: I've just edited my question with the output after linking the lib. And when once it happens, it never comes back to normal, I have to discard all modifications from my workspace and uninstall the lib to make my app able to build again.